# Листание между двумя фрагментами

Tags: android, android-fragment

как реализовать переход с одного фрагмента на другой, с помощью листания?

Comment: Если Вас интересует обычный переход, или Вы хотите понять как это работает, плюс-минус, то можете почитать что-то в этом плане - https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/178-urok-108-android-3-actionbar-navigatsija-taby-i-vypadajuschij-spisok.html . Также можете использовать уже готовые библиотеки. К примеру - https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar .

Comment: вам нужно использовать ViewPager